# Button dropdown wont work in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Hello</a> </li>   
                        <li><a href="#">Hi</a> </li>                          
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

This has been bugging me for hours already... I already inlcuded

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But still i can see no dropdown links for the list... Thanks in advance for any ideas/help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did u add reference to jQuery?

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
 <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You must have put references wrongly because your code works well with links.Recheck whether the path is correct.
check below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
 <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Hello</a> </li>   
                        <li><a href="#">Hi</a> </li>                          
                    </ul>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add `type="button"` to the `<button>` code, and if that doesnt fix it something else has to be messing with it, the coding looks right for the dropdown menus, so I'd need to see an example to be able to pin point it out.